# TCP/IP Server in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-cloud-services

I will start a new project on my company. This project consists in a TCP/IP socket integration between my company and a partner. The socket comunication is a restriction from the partner and this became a critical way for the project. We use azure as our main cloud services provider. That comunnication link will trafic approximately 5000 requests/min. I investigate a lot about how to do this in Azure and I discovered two ways:

1. Worker role on an Cloud Service
2. Use a Logic App

I'm not really full confortable with neither of the solutions yet. So, I just want an opinion about that solutions. If someone can give me some tips I will be really grateful. If there is another kind of solution, it will be welcome too.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: An Azure VM is another option, but not necessarily a cost-effective option.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to avoid this option. I don't not want to manage a VM for this integration. A PaaS solution I think is a better choice.

Comment: How about use azure web app and enable the [Web sockets](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/) in application settings?

Comment: But, can I open a port different from 80 and 443 in a webapp? The previous information I have is the comunication on an App service works only on 80 and 443.

Comment: You are right, you could not open ports in a web app.

Comment: I did a lot of research and I found another options. I can use a Service Fabric and a Container Service too. I'm gonna do a POC with all this features and evaluate wich is the best in my case.